# How to process only last event in a period?

Tags: rx-java2

I receive a lot of events with interval of a second. I want to precess the most recent event each second. eg
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15. 5 events per second.Thus i want proceed only events 5 on second 1, 10 on second 2,15 on second 3. I tohught about flowable  but it just introduce delay between events, and debounce will not trigger if event stream is constant

Comment: what is wrong with debounce? If i'm not mistaken it works as you described.When it comes to backpressure it is actual when elements are emmited faster then you handle them. Seems that one element per second won't be a problem

Comment: debounce will work only on last item if event was not received in some period. I basicly want to process 1 most recent event each  second.  Basicly prunning number of events i process.

Comment: Seems that throttleLast() is what you need.
[link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables#throttlelast)

Trying to find picture of throttleLast found this [link](https://medium.com/@doodeec/rxjava-caveats-of-throttle-s-7eacab183ccf)

Comment: @MikhailSidorov yes it is. thank you) please pos as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `throttleLast(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` is what you need. It emits only the last item emitted by a reactive source during sequential time windows of a specified duration.

[sample() operator rx docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html)

[throttleLast() description](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables#throttlelast)